# Slice string colum in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Guys i would like slice the column 'Delivey' in pandas line by line.
How i do that?

Actual Data:

| OF | Delivery |
| --- | --- |
| BR1000 | 888000; 888001 |
| BR1002 | 888002; 888003 |
| BR1003 | 88804 |

New data:

| OF | Delivery |
| --- | --- |
| BR1000 | 888000 |
| BR1000 | 888001 |
| BR1002 | 888002 |
| BR1002 | 888003 |
| BR1003 | 88804 |

Thanks,
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.split`:

```
>>> df.assign(Delivery=df['Delivery'].str.split('; ')).explode('Delivery')
       OF Delivery
0  BR1000   888000
0  BR1000   888001
1  BR1002   888002
1  BR1002   888003
2  BR1003    88804
```